# Ionic Firebase updateEmail "Cannot assign to 'email' because it is a read-only property."

Tags: javascript, firebase, vuejs3

Im a first time app builder, using Vue 3, Ionice and Firebase. I have managed to get the authentication in, which is working fine.

Now, I am trying to implement the update email functionality ([Docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/manage-users#set_a_users_email_address)

Unfortunately, the email is not set and the error I get is "Cannot assign to 'email' because it is a read-only property."

[image]

I don't understand why this is happening, as when I console.log, everything seems fine.

Here is my change-password component:

```
  <form class="login-form" autocomplete="off">
          <ion-item lines="full">
            <ion-label position="floating">New Email</ion-label>
            <ion-input v-model="updatedEmail" type="email"></ion-input>
          </ion-item>
          <ion-button expand="block" @click="doUpdateEmail">Update email</ion-button>
        </form>
```

Here is the script from this component:

```
<script>
import router from "@/router";
import { useAuthStore } from "@/store";

import {
  IonGrid,
  IonRow,
  IonCol,
  IonLabel,
  IonInput,
  IonItem,
  IonContent,
  IonHeader,
  IonTitle,
  IonToolbar,
  IonButton,
  IonPage, toastController
} from '@ionic/vue';
import { defineComponent, ref } from "vue";

export default defineComponent({
  components: {
    IonHeader,
    IonToolbar,
    IonTitle,
    IonContent,
    IonPage,
    IonGrid,
    IonRow,
    IonCol,
    IonLabel,
    IonInput,
    IonItem,
    IonButton
  },

  setup() {
    const { logoutUser, updateEmail, user, profile } = useAuthStore();
    const updatedEmail = ref('')
    const currentEmail = user.email


    const doLogout = async () => {
      await logoutUser();
      await router.replace("/login");
    };

    const doUpdateEmail = async () => {
      await updateEmail(user.email, updatedEmail.value).then(() => {
        // toast
        console.log('succes')
      })
          .catch(() => {
            // toast
            console.log('failed')
          });
    };

    return {
      updatedEmail,
      doLogout,
      doUpdateEmail,
      user,
      profile
    };
  },
});
</script>
```

And here is my store:

```
async updateEmail(email:string, updatedEmail: string) {
      try {
        if(this.user) {
         return this.user.email = updatedEmail
        }

      } catch (e: any) {
        this.error = e;
        return false;
      }
    },
```

EDIT: here is my entire store file:

```
import { User as fbUser } from "firebase/auth";
import { defineStore } from "pinia";
import {
  fbAuthStateListener,
  fbCreateAccount,
  fbGetUserProfile,
  fbSignIn,
  fbSignOut,
} from "./firebase";

export interface User {
  user: any;
  profile: any;
  userError: any;
}

interface State {
  user: fbUser | null;
  profile: any;
  error: null;
}


export const useAuthStore = defineStore("authStore", {
  // convert to a function
  state: (): State => ({
    user: null,
    profile: null,
    error: null,
  }),
  getters: {
    isLoggedIn: (state) => state.user !== null,
    userError: (state) => state.error,
  },
  actions: {
    initializeAuthListener() {
      return new Promise((resolve) => {
        fbAuthStateListener(async (user: any) => {
          this.user = user ? user : null;

          if (user) {
            const profile = (await fbGetUserProfile()) as any;
            this.profile = profile;
          }
          resolve(true);
        });
      });
    },

    async logInUser(email: string, password: string) {
      try {
        const response = await fbSignIn(email, password);
        this.user = response.user ? response.user : null;
        this.error = null;
        return true;
      } catch (e: any) {
        this.user = null;
        this.error = e;
        return false;
      }
    },
    async logoutUser() {
      try {
        await fbSignOut();
        this.user = null;
        this.profile = null;
        this.error = null;
        return true;
      } catch (e: any) {
        this.error = e;
        return false;
      }
    },

    async updateEmail(email:string, updatedEmail: string) {
      try {
        if(this.user) {
         return email = updatedEmail
        }


      } catch (e: any) {
        this.error = e;
        return false;
      }
    },
     async createAccount(email: string, password: string) {
        try {
          const {user, profile} = await fbCreateAccount(email, password);
          this.user = user ? user : null;
          this.profile = profile ? profile : null;
          this.error = null;
          return true;
        } catch (e: any) {
          this.user = null;
          this.error = e;
          return false;
        }
      },
  },

});
```

Comment: we need to see your whole store, specifically where you define the user

Comment: Thanks, I added my entire store